# Chrome Extension Manifest Upload Error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-app

i want to play with chrome extensions a little. So i began with this tutorial by google: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

After following these steps i already get an error which says that my manifest is invalid.

I only downloaded the files and put them in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer. Actually makes me look a little dumb..

I accidentally saved the file as an .txt instead of .json. So i did not change the way notepad saves the file but i just added an .json at the end what surely won't work.

So just save it as .json not as .txt.

Answer (score 0):

At what point did the error occurred? Check the directory of the folder and save the manifest file as ANSI format. Also, check the manifest file if the version is up to date. You may use "version": "3.1.2.4567".

Comment: The error occurs when i try to load the extension to chrome. It does not matter whether i drag&drop or use the normal function.

Ansi format did not help. Can you maybe link me the updated manifest because i can't find this version.

//Updated